# How to import my own Python packages

Tags: python, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
~/python_libs
    /markets
        Players.py
        Commodity.py
        Markets.py
        Currency.py
        __init__.py
```

and my `__init__.py` is this:

```
import numpy.random as rn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import gmtime, strftime
from datetime import datetime
```

I have set `$PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/python_lib` and verified that this has become part of `sys.path` (from `import sys`)

Now, I go into ipython and `import markets`

Nothing. It gives a blank line, but if I use, say `p=Player()` I get

> name 'Player' is not defined

I'm stumped. How do I import markets and have access to the modules in the markets package?

Comment: Python (unlike C and others) is very explicit about what ends up in the (global) namespace, so `import markets` will **only** create a name called `markets`. There isn't any magic side-effect that creates a `Player` name.

Answer (score 4):

If `Player` is defined in `markets.Players`, you'll need:

```
from markets.Players import Player
p = Player()
```

or:

```
import markets.Players
p = markets.Players.Player()
```

Either way, in Python you need to explicitly import what you need into your namespace.